# Android P - warning: "incompatible version of the Android OS"

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie

Running our app on device with Android P (9.0) - on the app start a warning is shown:

> (You app name) was built for an incompatible version of the Android OS
>   and may behave unexpectedly. An update version of the app may be
>   available.

We see it also on system app (i.e. Messages).

Any idea why and how can we overcome it?

[image: See image]

Comment: I have not seen this message, but I would suspect it is keying off something in the manifest: Target SDK, Permissions, Intent Filters, Screen Options...It might be worth editing/removing items in the manifest until the app starts normally to identify the source of the problem.

Comment: set targetSDK 28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the new version of Android P it doesn't occur.

Answer (score 0):

Does the (You app name) app or any of the libs that your app uses has a `uses-sdk maxSdkVersion` value in the manifest?

see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element

Comment: No it doesn't have such value.

Comment: you can check if any of the used libs has a maxSdkVersion  if you search for "maxSdkVersion" in all xml files in your build folder. there should be a generated (merged) manifest

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it by setting maxSdkVersion on 2 different phones. I know they use min & max on the playstore to prevent the app being served to an incompatible device. But that warning could be equally applicable to something like: "apps that target the API level 26 or higher can no longer register broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts in their manifest". If it has noticed that the app has registered intent filters for broadcasts it can longer receive it might issue a message like that...